# Delegate to an instance method cannot have null 'this' discord.net

Tags: c#, .net, delegates, .net-8.0, discord.net

I am developing a C# program in .NET 8

I have a generic host with a bunch of services for a discord bot. In one I have code like this
(simplified code)

```cs
public MessageService(DiscordSocketClient client, ILogger<DiscordClientService> logger)
    : base(client, logger)
{
    client.MessageUpdated += OnMessageUpdated;
}
private Task OnMessageUpdated(Cacheable<IMessage, ulong> oldMessage, SocketMessage newMessage, ISocketMessageChannel channel)
{
    Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        if (newMessage is not SocketUserMessage message) return;
        var context = new SocketCommandContext(Client, message);

        if (context.Channel.Id == _botOptions.ChannelId)
            await CheckChannelAsync(context);  // <--- Error here
    }
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
private async Task<bool> CheckChannelAsync(SocketCommandContext context)
{
    if (context.Message.Attachments.Count == 0)
    {
        string[] allowedSites = File.ReadAllLines(Utilities.GetLocalFilePath("AllowedSites.txt"));
        if (!Array.Exists(allowedSites, context.Message.Content.Contains))
        {
            string errorMessage = $"Your message doesn't contain any allowed website";
            await MessageDeleterHandlerAsync(context, errorMessage);
            return false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        var attachment = context.Message.Attachments.First();
        if (attachment.Width < 40 || attachment.Height < 40)
        {
            string errorMessage = $"The picture is too small!!";
            await MessageDeleterHandlerAsync(context, errorMessage);
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;

}
```

sometimes I get a burst of the same error triggering multiple times per minute and then it goes away for some days

System.ArgumentException:
Delegate to an instance method cannot have null 'this'.

```
   at System.MulticastDelegate.ThrowNullThisInDelegateToInstance()
   at MyBot.Services.MessageService.CheckChannelAsync(SocketCommandContext context)
   at MyBot.Services.MessageService.<>c__DisplayClass15_0.<<OnMessageUpdated>b__0>d.MoveNext() in /my/bot/Services/MessageService.cs:line 101
```

I don't know what the error message means. I'm not using delegates as far as I know so I don't know what to check to find out

I have tried logging if context is null but unsurprisingly it isn't as I dereference it fine before the error happens

This is using Discord.NET

EDIT: added the logic for CheckChannelAsync, also I'm not creating a delegate in the same way as the duplicate question so that one doesn't answer my question

Comment: The error happens _in_ `CheckChannelAsync`, so we'll have to see that to figure out what your problem is.

Comment: `// some logic` is what exactly?

Comment: @Charlieface I don't know but I'm 99% sure the bug is in there

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel ah my bad I added the method content in the edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem occurs when create a delegate directly from a method-group, i.e.

```cs
Action action = someObj.SomeMethod; // note not invoked
```

and it turns out that `someObj` is `null`; this isn't a `NullReferenceException`, but it is basically comparable. So: look for a method-group conversion (to a delegate), which could be an event subscription, and check that the target object is not `null`.

I can't see any of these in your code - the only candidate is:

```cs
client.MessageUpdated += OnMessageUpdated;
```

which is implicitly

```cs
client.MessageUpdated += this.OnMessageUpdated;
```

but we can we reasonably sure that `this` is not `null`; I'm guessing the real cause is in the code not shown. Note that the cause could be hidden in things like LINQ, for example:

```cs
.Where(filter.Clause)
```

if this is `IEnumerable<T>`, `Clause` is a method-group (most likely `bool Clause(T value)`), and `filter` turns out to be `null`.

Comment: thanks for the response. I added the code for the method. Sorry for that!
Yes it has LINQ but This error message confused me a lot and didn't think of LINQ

Comment: I'm guessing the issue is the predicate passed to `Array.Exists`: `context.Message.Content` has a null somewhere in there.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel: If `context` or `content.Message` were null, there would be an immediate NullReferenceException thrown by the member-access `context.Message.Content`.  It's only if `context.Message.Content` is null that we hit the situation described here of delegate binding and not member access.

Comment: I'm going to be logging `context.Message.Content` and see if it's null when this error fires. Thanks!

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel great spot, I missed that one - indeed, if `content.Message` is non-`null` and `context.Message.Content` is `null`, it would cause exactly this

Comment: I did some logging and this was indeed the case. The LINQ query. I was confused because the call stack didn't point to this line of code. Turns out `context.Message.Content` was indeed null. Wow what a weird error message. I'm grateful